# Drawing Circles Python

Tags: python, python-2.7

The function is supposed to loop, each time decreasing the size of the circle by 10 and drawing a new circle, until the size is less than or equal to 0. What am i missing

```
def circle(x):
    turtle.up()
    turtle.goto(0,0)
    turtle.down()
    turtle.color("blue")
    turtle.circle(x)
    if x>0:
        turtle.up()
        turtle.goto(0,0)
        turtle.down()
        turtle.color("blue")
        turtle.circle(x-10)
    else:
        turtle.up()
        turtle.goto(0,0)
        turtle.down()
        turtle.color("blue")
        turtle.circle(x)
print(circle(80))
```

Comment: You don't have any loop in your code

Comment: it's supposed to be recursive

Answer (score 4):

Here is a working version. Added recursion `circle(x-10)`, removed redundant code, added `turtle.done()` to stop the app from crashing.

```
import turtle
def circle(x):
    turtle.up()
    turtle.goto(0,0)
    turtle.down()
    turtle.color("blue")
    turtle.circle(x)
    if x>0:        
        circle(x-10)    
circle(80)
turtle.done()
```

Comment: There is still no loop.

Comment: It loops with no loop because of recursion - the function calls itself.

Answer (score 1):

Version with explicit loop:

```
import turtle
def circle(x):    
    while x > 0: 
        turtle.up()
        turtle.goto(0,0)
        turtle.down()
        turtle.color("blue")
        turtle.circle(x)
        x -= 10;
circle(80)
turtle.done()
```

Answer (score 0):

```
def ring_draw(dia,x0,y0):
    to_return=[]
    rad = dia / 2
    for x in xrange(x0+(rad+2)):
        for y in xrange(y0+(rad+2)):
            z0 = abs(x - x0)
            z1 = abs(y - y0)
            z2 = z0**2 + z1**2
            if rad**2 >= z2:
                to_return.append([x,y])
```